# Can't see dumb slave option

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

When I go on Manage Jenkins -> Node Management I can only add new "permanent" Agents and not the old "Dumb Slave" Node I used to have. Was there an update or something so this doesn't work anymore?

Also there in the manage node launch method the dropdown has only 3 options instead 5

Comment: When did you last see the "dumb slave" option? I think that is old. It's now named "permanent agent".

Comment: See also https://serverfault.com/questions/793619/jenkins-trying-to-add-a-dumb-slave-but-the-option-is-missing-any-idea-how-to-a

Answer (score 1):

They have changed the name of the dumb node to permanent agent as the result of the https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27268 ticket more over they do the same function